# Can you access a JSON representation of a value with javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I access the “JSON representation of a value” in javaScript?
I used `json_encode` and `echo` the result to an AJAX call and I get the json object which the PHP  manual refers to as  “json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value”.
Here is a short example of what I get when I console log the variable

```
{"RECORD_NUM":1002,"DATE_FIELD":"1747-01-19","DESCRIPTION":"Johann Bode founder of \"Bode's Law \" dies"},
{"RECORD_NUM":1111,"DATE_FIELD":"1770-01-19","DESCRIPTION":"Battle of Golden Hill (Lower Manhattan)"}]
```

The next step would be to parse "response"  with `JSON.parse`:

```
returnedArray=JSON.parse(response);
```

> To access the JSON object in JavaScript, parse it with JSON.parse(), and access it via “.” or “[]”.

If `JSON.parse` fails as it does in my case I ask the question “How can you cannot access the returned “JSON representation of a value.” ?”
Here is a small html file that I tested by declaring a javaScript variable but not with a “JSON representation of a value.”
This file works as I expected

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <title>JSON value</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <div>TODO write content</div>
    <!--Call a javaScript-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("document").ready(function () {
            var response = [
                {"RECORD_NUM": 967, "DATE_FIELD": "1736-01-19", "DESCRIPTION": "James Watt, inventor of the steam engine, was born in Scotland."},
                {"RECORD_NUM": 1002, "DATE_FIELD": "1747-01-19", "DESCRIPTION": "Johann Bode founder of \"Bode's Law \" dies"},
                {"RECORD_NUM": 1111, "DATE_FIELD": "1770-01-19", "DESCRIPTION": "Battle of Golden Hill (Lower Manhattan)"}
            ];
            dataCheck = response[0].DATE_FIELD;
            console.log("dataCheck = " + dataCheck + "\n");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Console prints:

```
dataCheck = 1736-01-19
```

If I use the code above in a AJAX success call I get an error:

```
            success: function (response) {
            console.log("Returned data = RESPONSE: \n" + response + "\n\n");
             dataCheck = response[0].DATE_FIELD;
            console.log("dataCheck = " + dataCheck + "\n");
```

Console log:

```
queryDatabase02.js:39 Returned data = RESPONSE: 
[{"RECORD_NUM":967,"DATE_FIELD":"1736-01-19","DESCRIPTION":"James Watt, inventor of the steam engine, was born in Scotland."},
{"RECORD_NUM":1002,"DATE_FIELD":"1747-01-19","DESCRIPTION":"Johann Bode founder of \"Bode's Law \" dies"},
{"RECORD_NUM":1111,"DATE_FIELD":"1770-01-19","DESCRIPTION":"Battle of Golden Hill (Lower Manhattan)"},
        ...
}]
```

So the question is, "How can I access the “JSON representation of a value” in javaScript?"
Answer-- "you can't"?

After checking for only one echo in the PHP file and also for sending the header I discovered that removing the header text right before the echo json_encoded
does not cause an error.  Here is the end of the PHP file:

```
// json_encode — Returns the JSON representation of a value
$jsonVal = json_encode($timeRtr);
$fileHandle = fopen('storage\jsonStorage', "a") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($fileHandle, $jsonVal);
fwrite($fileHandle, "\n");
fclose($fileHandle);
//header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo ($jsonVal);
```

?>
Here is the javascript file queryDataBase02.js

```
$("document").ready(function () {
$("button[name='History']").click(function (e) {
    // so the form does not get submitted
    e.preventDefault();
    var displayStr = "";
    var theQuery = {queryString: "SELECT * FROM time_table WHERE" +
                " EXTRACT(MONTH FROM DATE_FIELD ) = DATE_FORMAT(NOW()," +
                " '%c')  AND  EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_FIELD ) = DATE_FORMAT    (NOW     (), '%e')" +
                " ORDER BY DATE_FIELD]}"};
    console.log("\t THEObject = " + theQuery + "\n");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        //                   dataType: "json",
        url: "queryDatabase02.php",
        data: theQuery,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("Returned data = RESPONSE: \n" + response + "\n\n");
            dataCheck = response[0].DATE_FIELD;
            console.log("dataCheck on response " + dataCheck + " \n");


            // How big is response
            responseCnt = response.length;
            console.log("responseCnt = " + responseCnt + "\n");

            // Access the data ...
            displayArray = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log("THIS IS display STRING:\n" + displayArray + "\n");
            dataCheck = displayArray[0].DATE_FIELD;
            console.log("dataCheck Second time = " + dataCheck + "\n");
            console.log("LEAVING .............\n");
        }
    });
    return false;
    });
});
```

Here is the console out put for both with and without the header in the PHP file.

```
WITH -- "header('Content-Type: application/json');"

queryDatabase02.js:10    THEObject = [object Object]
queryDatabase02.js:17 Returned data = RESPONSE: 
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

queryDatabase02.js:19 dataCheck on response 1736-01-19 
queryDatabase02.js:24 responseCnt = 28
VM211:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
$.ajax.success  @   queryDatabase02.js:27
i   @   jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2
j.fireWith  @   jquery-2.2.0.min.js:2
z   @   jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4
(anonymous function)    @   jquery-2.2.0.min.js:4
==========================================================
```

WITHOUT  -- "header('Content-Type: application/json');"

```
 THEObject = [object Object]

queryDatabase02.js:17 Returned data = RESPONSE: 
[{"RECORD_NUM":967,"DATE_FIELD":"1736-01-19","DESCRIPTION":"James Watt,         inventor of the steam engine, was born in Scotland."},
{"RECORD_NUM":1002,"DATE_FIELD":"1747-01-19","DESCRIPTION":"Johann Bode         founder of \"Bode's Law \" dies"},
{"RECORD_NUM":1111,"DATE_FIELD":"1770-01-19","DESCRIPTION":"Battle of     Golden     Hill (Lower Manhattan)"},
....
"}]


queryDatabase02.js:19 dataCheck on response undefined 

queryDatabase02.js:24 responseCnt = 4948

queryDatabase02.js:28 THIS IS display STRING:
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object         Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object         Object],
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],
```

....
    [object Object]

```
queryDatabase02.js:30 dataCheck Second time = 1736-01-19

queryDatabase02.js:31 LEAVING .............
```

Lastly I noted the record count difference with and without the header information from the PHP file.

Comment: Have you tried JSON.Parse(response)?

Comment: You already have the answer to your "specific" question... "How can I access the JSON representation of a value"? ... it's `json_encode()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: You're missing the call to `JSON.parse()` in the `success` function. You can also use `dataType: "json"` in the `$.ajax` call, and jQuery will automatically parse the response for you.

Comment: What error are you getting when you try to use `JSON.parse(response)`?

Comment: Make sure the PHP script isn't outputting anything other than the `echo json_encode()` call. Go to the Network tab of Developer Tools and look at the Response to the call, and make sure there's no HTML before or after the JSON.

Comment: Also, make sure your PHP page is outputting the proper header prior to calling json_encode - header('content-type:application/json');

Comment: I checked the network connection and found no current echo beside the echo json_encode.

Comment: The fact that you're able to do `response[0].DATA_FIELD` says that you're already parsing your JSON, so you don't need to parse it again.